# TPT 'æ' Delimiter

Tags: ascii, teradata, delimiter

I am trying to use 'æ' as character as Delimiter of a TPT... it does not work. Is there any way to specify the ASCII code as delimiter?

```
ATTRIBUTES
(
VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'dataconnector_log',
VARCHAR DirectoryPath  = @jobvar_datafiles_path,
VARCHAR FileName       = @jobvar_file_load,
VARCHAR Format         = 'Delimited',
VARCHAR OpenMode       = 'Read',
VARCHAR TextDelimiter  = '    VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'dataconnector_log',
VARCHAR DirectoryPath  = @jobvar_datafiles_path,
VARCHAR FileName       = @jobvar_file_load,
VARCHAR Format         = 'Delimited',
VARCHAR OpenMode       = 'Read',
VARCHAR TextDelimiter  = 'æ'
);
```

> VARCHAR TextDelimiter  = 'æ'

Comment: ASCII 145 is a left single quotation mark.  I do not believe that 'æ' is an ASCII character.  Here is a link to the ASCII table: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @DavidCram That is inaccurate. ASCII deals with the range 0 through 127 only. So if you have eight bits, you will have to interprete. For ["DOS" code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), 145 corresponds to __æ__, U+00E6 LATIN SMALL LETTER AE. For the [code page Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), 145 is __‘__ U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK. For Latin-1 or ISO/IEC 8859-1 or code page Windows-28591 and similar, 145 (hexadecimal 91) "stands for itself", the control character U+0091 PRIVATE USE ONE. And I only mentioned a few code pages!

Comment: @DavidCram And of course to get __æ__ (U+00E6 LATIN SMALL LETTER AE) in both Windows-1252 and real Latin-1, you use the byte value 230 (= hex E6), and that is also in your reference `ascii-code.com`. Related to the answer given by the asker himself.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Good point.  I didn't look at the extended ASCII codes.  I only checked the value referenced in the original question (145).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in teradata the way to do this, is to put the hex-code of the character

```
  ATTRIBUTES
  (
    VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'dataconnector_log',
    VARCHAR DirectoryPath  = @jobvar_datafiles_path,
    VARCHAR FileName       = @jobvar_file_load,
    VARCHAR Format         = 'Delimited',
    VARCHAR OpenMode       = 'Read',
    VARCHAR TextDelimiterHex  = 'E6'    
  );
```

> VARCHAR TextDelimiterHex  = 'E6'

Answer (score 0):

Although the original question has been marked as answered, I will post a somewhat relevant piece of info that I found very had to find out out of the infos and docs available online.

If you need to specify a special character as TDLOAD's (Teradata Easy Load Utility) field delimiter, you can do it using a hexadecimal representation of the character. In my case that was an unprintable character in a unicode encoding. However, when I was executing

```
tdload ... --SourceTextDelimiterHEX "01"
```

I was receiving the following error

```
$FILE_READER[1]: TPT19128 !ERROR! Attribute 'TextDelimiter' conflicts with 'TextDelimiterHEX'
```

To the best of my knowledge, this issue is neither documented or discussed anywhere, which I find really strange. Luckily, I was able to resolve it by specifying the empty TextDelimiter like this

```
tdload ... --SourceTextDelimiterHEX "01" -d ""
```

I hope it might help someone.